# What causes blurry fonts in Qt applications (in XFCE desktop)?

Tags: fonts, qt

I am using Xubuntu 12.04 with XFCE 4.8

Fonts in Qt-based apps like VLC look blurry in my user profile, as if anti-aliasing was turned off. Chrome has the same problem.

The problem is not system-wide though: in another user profile on the same machine, I have tried a couple of Qt applications and they look fine there.

Comment: Is it possible to have some screenshots ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this post: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2032512

In my case, it was enough to remove `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xsettings.xml` (I removed `~/.cache/sessions` too).
I still don't know the real reason for the problem though.